# How to replace an item in inventory? (1.16.5)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I want the item to be replaced with an another item when the overridden function fires.

```java
    @Override
    public ActionResultType itemInteractionForEntity(ItemStack stack, PlayerEntity playerIn, LivingEntity target, Hand hand) {

        if (!playerIn.world.isRemote()) {
            // Replace an item with xyz
        }

        return super.itemInteractionForEntity(stack, playerIn, target, hand);
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Note: I'm using MCP mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it like this:

```java
// Within your ItemA class
@Override
public ActionResultType itemInteractionForEntity(ItemStack stack, PlayerEntity playerIn, LivingEntity target,
    Hand hand) {

    // To make sure the code runs on the server
    if (playerIn.world.isRemote()) {
        return super.itemInteractionForEntity(stack, playerIn, target, hand);
    }

    // We check if the item is held in the main hand, if so we do the
    // main hand item sawp. This check prevents usage of the item from
    // the secondary hand too. If there was no check at all we could put
    // the item in our left hand and use it in order to get a new item in
    // our right hand.

    if (playerIn.getHeldItemMainhand().getItem() instanceof ItemA) {
        // ItemRegistrator just holds static refrences to all my registered items
        ItemStack itemB = new ItemStack(ItemRegistrator.ITEM_B.get()); 

        playerIn.setHeldItem(Hand.MAIN_HAND, itemB);
    }

    return super.itemInteractionForEntity(stack, playerIn, target, hand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `stack` item. Example :

```
@Override
public ActionResultType itemInteractionForEntity(ItemStack stack, PlayerEntity playerIn, LivingEntity target, Hand hand) {
    if (!playerIn.world.isRemote()) {
        stack = myNewItem;
        // or just directly edit item:
        stack.setAmount(1); // example
    }
    return super.itemInteractionForEntity(stack, playerIn, target, hand);
}
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track but that just changes the stack item within the function's context as opposed to changing the block in the inventory of the player who right clicked an entity instead.